# Convert int to unsigned char array and backwards

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n = 56789000;
    unsigned char bytes[4];

    bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
    bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
    bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
    bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;

    int test = (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[0]);

    printf("%d\n",n);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Output is:

```c
56789000
143155715
```

Hello,

I'm trying to store an integer into an unsigned char array and want to convert it back to an integer later. I found some code-snippets which lead me to the code above but the output is not as expected. Can you please help to fix the code above. I'm not very familiar with C and don't know what is wrong with the code.

Thank in advance

Comment: "he output is not as expected" What are you expecting?

Comment: I would expect that the same number will be printed twice.

Comment: I wouldn't since you're setting bytes[0] to the top 8 bits but then re-assembling with it as the lower 8 bits (and the same for the others). Try printing it in hex (%x) and all will become obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is in the opposite order

```
int test = (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[0]);
```

so

```
int test = (bytes[0] << 24) | (bytes[1] << 16) | (bytes[2] << 8) | (bytes[3]);
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should have tried that. Have nice day.